# Import package based on pdflatex or xelatex

Tags: pdftex

I want to import a package if pdflatex is being used otherwise I do not want to import it so that I don't have to comment/uncomment them every time I change the compiler.

For example, pdfrender does not work with xelatex. So is there a way to tell latex to import with \usepackage{pdfrender} and subsequence commands only when the compiler is pdflatex?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{pdfrender}
\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2}

%\usepackage{fontspec}

\author{Masum Billal}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    This is a test file. %Citing \textcite{lehmer1900},
\end{document}
```

Comment: check the iftex package. It offers a number of such tests.

Comment: thank you it worked. is it possible to accept comment as answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `iftex` package, if offers a number of engine tests, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\pdfrender{TextRenderingMode=2}
\fi
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\author{Masum Billal}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    This is a test file. %Citing \textcite{lehmer1900},
\end{document}
```